# Rails 3 : Convert to Float in Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I my Rails application i have a Register Model which contains attendance status of each users.I want to show no of users present on current day (in Percentage).I have found Total no of users Present Today from Register Table and Expected Users from another table.

```
@totalnoofuserspresent = Register.where(:date => date).sum(:one)
@expectedusers = Workoutplanperday.where(:day => date , :workoutplantype => 1).count 

attendance = @totalnoofuserspresent / @expectedusers  (ie: 5/10 )
```

Currently i am getting `attendance:0`

I want to display it in Percentage ie: 50% or in float ie: 0.50

Thanks in advance....

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is, that both variables (@totalnoofuserpresent and @expectedusers) are integers. Ruby assumes you want an integer back, if you you are doing an operation with integers only. So you must convert one of the variables to a float before you do the division.

```
attendance = Float(@totalnoofuserspresent) / @expectedusers
```

or easier

```
attendance = @totalnoofuserspresent.to_f / @expectedusers
```

Comment: is there a more elegant solution?

Comment: i read something like number_to_percentage(100, :precision => 0) . http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/NumberHelper.html#method-i-number_to_percentage